Does Cache-Control: s-maxage=31536000 guarantee no revalidation by intermediaries (CDN, proxies)?
I am trying to optimize the caching of versioned static files (e.g., style.abc123.css) served through a CDN or proxy cache. I am currently using the following HTTP header:
Cache-Control: s-maxage=31536000

My understanding is that this directive tells shared caches (like CDNs or proxies) to serve the cached resource for up to one year (31536000 seconds) without revalidating it with the origin server.
However, I have a couple of questions:

Does s-maxage=31536000 alone guarantee that no conditional revalidation (e.g., via If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match) will occur during this period, even if a client forces a refresh or revalidation?

If not, is it necessary to add the immutable directive (e.g., Cache-Control: s-maxage=31536000, immutable) to ensure that no revalidation happens at all?


I would appreciate clarification on this behavior to ensure I am correctly optimizing caching for these static resources.
Thank you in advance!
It was difficult to debug this. Most articles recommend adding immutable, but I don’t understand the rationale behind it.

I see that you're well educated on the subtleties of the Cache-Control header. Since yo used the #varnish tag, I'll explain how Varnish approaches this.
Setting the TTL
In terms of the TTL, varnish will prioritize whatever is set in the VCL through set beresp.ttl. Then it will look for the s-maxage directive in the Cache-Control header. Next in line is the max-age directive in the Cache-Control header. The Expires header has the lowest priority.
If none of these are set, the default_ttl runtime parameter will be used to determine the TTL of an object. This parameter has a default value of 2 minutes.
Avoiding conditional revalidation
Varnish has no awareness of the immutable directive, however you could write VCL code to mimic its behavior.
If a cache miss takes place, or a cache hit returns an expired object, revalidation will take place under the form of a fetch.
If you don't want this to be conditional, I suggest you strip off the If-None-Match header before the backend request take place. You'd use the following VCL for that:
sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    unset bereq.http.If-None-Match;
}

Avoiding asynchronous revalidation
Conditional revalidation can also happen asynchronously will stale date is being served. That amount of seconds beyond the expiration of the object, is defined through the default_grace runtime parameter.
If you don't want asynchronous revalidation to take place either, simply add stale-while-revalidate=0 to your Cache-Control header, or use the following VCL code:
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.grace = 0s;
}

How Varnish deals with other Cache-Control directives
Varnish also has no awareness of he following Cache-Control directives:

must-revalidate
proxy-revalidate
immutable
stale-if-error
no-transform
must-understand

Although Varnish does react to the no-cache, no-store, and private directives, it treats them the same way by bypassing the cache.

Oh, thank you for your response. Alright, I understand the idea of setting the max age to one year, but what’s really the purpose of adding the immutable attribute? It just ensures that the browser won’t revalidate the resource with my server. But honestly, does it really make a difference?

If you're using versioned static files then you want them be cached forever. So there's no reason to limit yourself to using s-maxage, which just applies to shared caches; use max-age instead. And, yes, add immutable as well, since that allows the browser to use the cached asset even when the user reloads. In sum, use:
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, immutable

Do note that there's nothing you can do to force clients to use your cached assets. Caching is an optional part of HTTP, and of course the client is free to empty its cache at any time. So nothing you can do will "guarantee" that the client doesn't try to fetch the asset.

Oh, thank you for your response. Alright, I understand the idea of setting the max age to one year, but what’s really the purpose of adding the immutable attribute? It just ensures that the browser won’t revalidate the resource with my server. But honestly, does it really make a difference?
